# How to enable image to return to top of screen when user is not interacting

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

***Functionality:***
User is to tap a "TAP HERE" image to bring the star that is at the top of the page to the bottom at the quickest time or within the counter. And when user decides to leave the finger off the "TAP HERE" image, the star will automatically elevate back to the top "orignal" position.

***What has been done:***

I have managed to get a script that allows user to tap on the "TAP HERE" image to move the star down.

***Issue:***
I have no idea on how to move the star back to the top automatically when users stop interacting with the tap image.

I have attached the code for your perusal

```js
function GameStart() {
  console.log("GameStart");
  //Method to enable star to decrease when 'tap' button is tapped
  var step = 10;
  var x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;
  x = x + step;
  document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";
}
```

```css
#GameStar {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6.5em;
  left: 500px;
  width: auto;
  height: 1050px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="background-image: url(lib/Elements/Background.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; width:100%; height:100%;z-index=1;">
  <audio src="lib/Elements/happy.mp3" loop autoplay>Your browser does not support this audio format</audio>
  <div id="CountdownFadeInTimer" align="center"></div>
  <img id="GameStar" type="image" src="lib/Elements/The%20Star.png">
  <input id="Tap" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Tap%20here%20button.png" onclick="GameStart()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Given that you're using HTML elements to do everything, maybe you can try onmouseup event? You can create another function that does the reverse of GameStart() and tied it to the event.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onmouseup.asp

**EDIT:**

After getting a bit more information, it seems I was having the wrong idea. Below are a simple sample that would simulate the effect that was asked. There are 2 timers one to start counting after the user click and the other is to decrease the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click" onClick=onClick()>Click Here</button>
    <p id="xText">X : 0</p>

    <script>
        //The x value (increased by clicking the button, decreased automatically by timer)
        var x = 0;

        //Values for the 1st timer (run after the user click the button)
        var cTimer = null;
        var currentTime = 0;    //how many seconds have passed since the button last clicked
        var maximumTime = 5;    //how many seconds after last click before we start decreasing

        //Values for the 2nd timer (run after 1st timer ends)
        var dTimer = null;
        var dCurrentTime = 0;   //how many seconds have passed since the current interval started
        var dMaximumTime = 3;   //the decreasing interval in seconds

        //This is called each time the user clicked the button
        function onClick(){
            //Increase the value of x by 1
            UpdateXValue(1);

            //clear out all timer and timer value
            currentTime = 0;
            dCurrentTime = 0;
            clearTimeout(dTimer);
            clearTimeout(cTimer);

            //start new timer
            cTimer = setTimeout(RunTimer, 1000);
        }

        //This function acts as timer that runs after the button is clicked
        function RunTimer(){
            currentTime += 1;

            //if the time passed since last button clicked is less than "maximumTime" run the timer again
            //else stops the timer and start the second timer to decrease x's value
            if (currentTime < maximumTime){
                cTimer = setTimeout(RunTimer, 1000);
            }else{
                clearTimeout(cTimer);
                dTimer = setTimeout(DecreaseValue, 1000);
            }
        }

        //This function acts as timer to decrease the X value that runs after the 1st timer is done
        function DecreaseValue(){
            dCurrentTime += 1;

            //if the second timer have reach the interval for decreasing value (dMaximumTime)
            //else keep running the timer
            if (dCurrentTime >= dMaximumTime){
                //decrease the value of x by 1
                UpdateXValue(-1);

                //if x is still larger than 0 run the timer again
                //else stops the timer
                if (x > 0){
                    dCurrentTime = 0;
                    dTimer = setTimeout(DecreaseValue, 1000);
                }else{
                    clearTimeout(dTimer);
                }
            }else{
                dTimer = setTimeout(DecreaseValue, 1000);
            }
        }

        //Update X by the value sent
        function UpdateXValue(valueToAdd){
            x += valueToAdd;
            document.getElementById("xText").innerHTML = "X : " + x.toString();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using an onClick function. Does onMouseUp and onMouseDown method works for an screen interaction

Comment: Seems like I might have misunderstood something, so let me confirm something; what do you mean by "stop interacting"? Btw yes, as you can see from the example on the page, you can use it to detect when user interact with an element on the page.

Comment: "Stop Interacting"-> when the user stops tapping on the "TAP HERE" image.

Comment: Let me see if understand correctly; the user click the image -> the value increase and when the user stops interacting (didn't click the image for a few seconds) the value got reset. Is this correct?

Comment: the user click the image -> the step value increase and when the user stops interacting (didn't click the image for a few seconds) the step value decreases and position will be reset. The main image will move from the top to the bottom when the user clicks on the "TAP HERE" image button, and when user do not tap on the "TAP HERE" image button, the main image will move back up the line and return to the original position

Comment: I edited my answer to include a sample that would simulate what you're saying (I didn't draw any image though).

Comment: It's because I never show the value X anywhere (just printed it in the console). I've edited the code so that the value is shown on the page instead. I'm honestly not sure about jsfiddle.... but if you tried to copy the sample code and save it as HTML, it should show a page with a button and a text (X value). Each time you click the button, the value increase and after 5 seconds of last clicked a second timer will run that will decrease the value.

Comment: So I reckon, it should be the same for an image that is moving up and down??set 2 timer, one for moving down and the other for moving back up? don't mind, please do add in some comments please?

Comment: Not for moving down as the step value is increased each time the image is clicked. The 2 timer in the code is for checking how many seconds passed since user clicked the button, and the interval for decreasing the value. I've edited the code to make some minor adjustments and add comments.

Comment: ok!!it works with values, but I am not really sure on how this is integrated with what I have. I have tried the following code without using the numbers but it is not working. Is there any easier method for e.g: that uses a counter?